Local Microsoft SQL Server cannot be found from .NET Core Solution launched through Docker
The issue that I am encountering is that when I start a .NET Core project with Docker, the Microsoft SQL Server which runs locally (not as a container) cannot be found. The response of Swagger UI is displayed below.

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

This is my connection string
Server=host.docker.internal,1433;Database=myDb;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;

I have enabled TCP/IP for MSSQLSERVER, I have set 1433 as TCP port and I have disabled Windows Firewall for Domain Networks.
Should I modify anything else in the docker-compose.override.yaml file (maybe something related to environment)?
NOTE: In my SQL Server Network Configuration, I see SQLEXPRESS instead of MSSQLSERVER. Could somehow this affect the situation?

"In my SQL Server Network Configuration, I see SQLEXPRESS instead of MSSQLSERVER. Could somehow this affect the situation ?" Yes, it will. You are trying to connect to a default instance not a named instance.

@ThomA Ok, thanks. How should I address this ?

Instead of host.docker.internal,1433 try host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS.

Did you restart the SQLEXPRESS instance after enabling and reconfiguring its TCP/IP server protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager? These changes don't take immediate effect, the service needs to be restarted.

set the connection string Server=host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=myDb;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; yaml file:version: '3.4'   services:        myapp:          environment:            - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=myDb;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; make sure remote connection is allowed in sql. have tried accesing the sql server from different machine?

@JalpaPanchal It's quite unlikely SQLEXPRESS is on 1433. Named instances typically use a different port precisely so they don't interfere with the port usually used by the default (non-named) instance. So, specify the instance name or the port, but not both.

After long investigation I found out that host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS,1433 works after all. It also mattered that I was attempting through a secure HTTP conection (https://...) instead of HTTP, which has as a result the non-fetching of the resource (as HTTPS requires further server-side configuration). Thank you all for your entries.

Valid input in .env file when launching Microsoft SQL Studio through the EXPRESS instance:
host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS,1433
